# Name Error when defining function inside other function

Tags: python

I am creating a text based game and trying to define the next function with an if/else statement so that the player can decide if they want to progress in the game or not. It is working on the previous line but stops working in the nested else statement.

```
def Baker_Street ():
  print("""
      A man named Henry Knight comes to visit you and Watson, to understand something that has plagued him   
      his whole life. 
      Henry witnessed his father's death by a gigantic hound at Dartmoor 20 years ago.
      After years of therapy Henry finally visited the site of the incident again, 
      and to his shock and surprise sees the hound again, which prompts his request for help.
      """, end= '')
  t.sleep(5)
  clear()
  type("\nDo you agree to help Mr.Knight and solve this mystery? Y/N")
  choice = input(">>> ")
  if choice.lower == "Y":                                                 
   dartmoor_inn()
  else:
    print("Are you sure? Y/N")
    if choice.lower== "Y":
     exit()
    else:
     print('Great Choice! Onto Dartmoor Inn.')
     dartmoor_inn() #this is where it stops
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 83, in <module>
    Baker_Street()   
  File "main.py", line 81, in Baker_Street
    dartmoor_inn()
NameError: name 'dartmoor_inn' is not defined

```

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly tells you what the error is:

```
NameError: name 'dartmoor_inn' is not defined
```

So the code is calling a function which has not yet been defined !

The code in the question is also missing an import:

```
import time as t
```

And also, `clear()` is not a function, so it needs to be removed.

Finally, it needs to call the function `Baker_Street()`. The naming convention is usually **snake case**.

And i should point out that accepted indentation is generally 4 spaces.

With all of the above considered it can be fixed like this:

```py
import time as t

def dartmoor_inn():
    print('do something here')


def Baker_Street ():
  print("""
      A man named Henry Knight comes to visit you and Watson, to understand something that has plagued him   
      his whole life. 
      Henry witnessed his father's death by a gigantic hound at Dartmoor 20 years ago.
      After years of therapy Henry finally visited the site of the incident again, 
      and to his shock and surprise sees the hound again, which prompts his request for help.
      """, end= '')
  t.sleep(5)
  
  type("\nDo you agree to help Mr.Knight and solve this mystery? Y/N")
  choice = input(">>> ")
  if choice.lower == "Y":                                                 
   dartmoor_inn()
  else:
    print("Are you sure? Y/N")
    if choice.lower== "Y":
     exit()
    else:
     print('Great Choice! Onto Dartmoor Inn.')
     dartmoor_inn() #this is where it stops

Baker_Street()
```